# What do the lines mean in Intellij Idea Git Log?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, branch, git-log

You can see the git log window by pressing alt + 9 in Idea:

[image]

I see those dots represent commits. Do these lines represent branches? If so, how to figure out which branch does each line represent?

I see if I hover some parts of a line, part of it gets highlighted, what does the highlighted part mean? If I click it, it changes to a dotted line. What just happened?

[image]

Are there articles or videos that explain Idea git log window or the tree-like git log structure it uses in detail? I have read [Idea's help page for git log window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html), but few words were about the lines.

Answer (score 6):

Part of your question is:

> Do these lines represent branches? If so, how to figure out which branch does each line represent?

I mentioned in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734599/what-do-the-lines-mean-in-intellij-idea-git-log#comment119725994_67734703) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734599/what-do-the-lines-mean-in-intellij-idea-git-log#comment119726025_67734703) that they do represent ... something we might well *call* branches:

- The word *branch* tends to lose all meaning in Git so it's not really clear when to use the word at all, other than as a modifier to *name*.  If we say that `master` is a *branch name*, and `develop` is a *branch name*, and so on, these are pretty clear.  Technically `master` is shorthand for `refs/heads/master`, which is a *ref* or *reference:* it's a way to hold a commit hash ID.<sup>1</sup>
- But we also need a way to refer to some group of commits.  We tend to call that *a branch* as well.
- Git offers *remote-tracking names* such as `origin/master`.  We often call the set of commits found with such a name a *remote branch*, and Git itself calls these things *remote-tracking branch names* even though they're not *branch* names.<sup>2</sup>

I find that the word *branch* is overused to the point of often becoming meaningless.  But the lines represent *links* from commits to other, earlier commits.

We find these links by going from commit to commit.  When we find the *starting* commit, for following these commit-to-commit links, using a *branch name*, we call this a *branch*.  But this isn't the same thing as the *branch name*, and the problem here becomes clear when we look at how these evolve over time.

Let's start with a repository with just three commits in it, all on `master` or `main`, and draw those three commits using uppercase letters instead of the big ugly hash IDs that Git really uses for them:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
```

The *name* `main` holds the hash ID of the *last* of the three commits, commit `C`.  Commit `C` itself holds the raw hash ID of earlier commit `B`, and commit `B` holds the raw hash ID of still-earlier commit `A`.  We say that `C` *points to* `B`, and `B` *points to* `A`—and of course `main` itself points to C.

Commit `A` was the very first commit.  There is no earlier commit!  So commit `A` doesn't point anywhere.  This makes it a *root commit* and Git can stop going backwards here.

We now add a new branch name to our collection of commits.  This new name *also points to commit `C`*, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main, develop
```

We pick one name to *use* with `git checkout`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main, develop (HEAD)
```

We're now using commit `C`, via the name `develop`.  If we `git checkout main` we're still using `C`, just via a different name, but we'll stick with `develop` for now.

Each commit holds a snapshot of every file, frozen for all time, in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* form.  So the fact that most of the files in `C` are probably identical to those in `B` means that `C` doesn't take much extra space.  If `B` and `C` share a 100 MB file unchanged, there's only one *copy* of that file.

But these files can't be used by anything else.  So `git checkout` has to *copy them out* to a usable form.  That's what is in your *working tree:* the usable-form copies.  We won't go any further with this idea, but it's worth keeping in mind and revisiting later.

Anyway, let's now make a new commit `D`, in the usual way.  Commit `D` will hold a (de-duplicated) snapshot of every file as usual, and will point backwards to existing commit `C`.  When Git has finished making `D`, Git will update the *current branch name*, whatever that is—based on the attachment of `HEAD`—to point to `D`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commits `A-B-C` are now on `main`, right?  And `D` is only on `develop`.  Well, the *last* part is right—but commits `A-B-C` are *also on `develop`*.

The lines your viewer draws, that connect `D` backwards to `C` and so on, don't tell you which *branch* something is on, in part because the *branches don't matter*.  Only the *commits* matter.  Commit `C` matters, and can be found from both names, so it's on both branches.  That one line linking `C` backwards to `B` represents *two* branches right now.

We might go on and make a few more commits:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D--E--F   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

It's tempting to think of these as separate, as if `develop` has *only* `D-E-F`.  That's not the case in Git: the branch names only matter for getting started.  We never know when to *stop*, except if we hit a root commit like `A`.

To get Git to stop earlier than that, we use expressions like `main..develop`.  This is shorthand for `develop ^main`.  This uses set theory: via `develop`, we find *all* commits, and then via `main` we find the `A-B-C` set, and we subtract the excluded set—the `^main` part—from the whole.  That leaves us with `D-E-F`, which are the commits we might want to think of as being "on branch `develop`".  But to get there, we had to say: *commits that are on `develop`, minus commits that are on `main`* because `A-B-C` are on *both branches*.

Now we may go on to *merge* the new commits *into* `main`.  When we do that, we can let Git do a *fast-forward*, which is not a merge at all:

```
git checkout main && git merge --ff-only develop
```

results in:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

Now *all six commits are on both branches*.  There's now only a single line, instead of two lines: we don't have to break up our drawing to have `main` point to `C` any more.

Or, we can use an explicit merge, or maybe make a commit on `main` first:

```
git checkout main; (... make new commit ...); git merge develop
```

which results in:

```
A--B--C------G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
       \       /
        D--E--F   <-- develop
```

where commit `H` is a *merge commit*.  There are two backwards-pointing arrows coming out of `H`: one connects to earlier commit `G` (if we made it, or `C` directly if not), and the other points to commit `F`.  Now *all commits are on `main`*.  The merge commit `H` is *only* on `main` (at least for now), but because it points backwards to both ... whatever-we-call-a-set-of-commits, all those commits are *reachable from* commit `H`, so all commits are "on" `main`.  There are two lines, but only one branch used to find them **so far**.

Of course there's also that name `develop`, which finds commit `F`, which finds commit `E`, and so on, all the way back to `A`.  Commit `F` is therefore on branch `develop`, just like it used to be.  It's just that it's on branch `main` *too* now.

But: now we can *delete the name `develop` entirely*, with `git branch -d develop`.  When we do, we are left with this:

```
A--B--C------G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
       \       /
        D--E--F
```

All the commits remain.  There are still two lines.  But now there is only one *branch name* involved.

This is why I like to say that *branch names do not matter*—other than for finding the one commit of course.  We need *some* way to find commit `H`.  As long as we have that, we find all the earlier commits too, because they're linked, one—or for merge commit `H`, two—at a time, backwards.

The lines in your visualizer represent these linkages.  The linkages are branches, or aren't branches, or are whatever you like, depending on how you want to view them.

---

<sup>1</sup>We also end up with, in `.git/config`, a configuration section:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

for instance, so there's more to a branch name than *just* the commit hash ID.  But these two entries are mostly-static: the `remote` and `merge` settings change if we run `git branch --set-upstream-to`, for instance, to change the *upstream* setting of `master`.

<sup>2</sup>Running `git checkout origin/master` and then `git status`, we see that this produces a *detached HEAD* status, rather than an `on branch origin/master` status.  So `origin/master`—whose full spelling is `refs/remotes/origin/master`—is not a *branch* name.  Since the word *branch* is so badly beaten-up from overuse in Git, calling this a *remote-tracking branch name* is, I think, a bad idea.  The phrase *remote-tracking name* works just as well for identifying what kind of name this is.

Comment: tl;dr. A quick summary would have been good as I needed to understand this and unblock myself.

Answer (score 3):

From your screen captures : when you see the gray dots, you can see that there is a linear sequence of commits, without any merge, that gets highlighted when you hover over it.

Apparently : clicking on the hovered line hides this sequence of commits, and allows you to focus on the other branches.
The line gets dashed probably to indicate "there are hidden commits there, between the two ends of this line".
Clicking on the dotted line makes these commits visible again.

I don't know how IntelliJ chooses what sequences can be collapsed ; my blind guess is : it probably keeps commits involved in merges, and commits which are pointed to by a reference (a branch, a tag or a remote branch).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **dots** are commits and **lines** are branches.

To know to which branch it refers is enough to look at the right pane like in the following image:

[image]

The dotted line simply represents the branch you selected by clicking on a commit of its own.

Comment: Technically, a line is not a branch as a branch is just a pointer to a commit. The lines represent the history of commits (what commits happened before) (and that is equvalent to the history of the branch).

Comment: A commit exists on at least a branch, and a list of commits is the branch history.

Comment: Branch history: yes but the lines are **not** the branches as branches are just references to commits (actually files just containing the commit hash and a line break).

Comment: This illustrates the problem with the word *branch*.  Is a Git branch a *branch name* like `master`, or is it a set of commits connected by connecting lines, or what? The answer to that question tends to be "yes". This means that we need to figure out what the "what" is before we proceed. We might as well say that the dots are commits and the lines are cronkins and `master` is a cronkin and we want to create a new cronkin etc. It has just as much meaning as `branch`, i.e., none until we figure out what the heck we meant.

Comment: Still, this *is* the right answer. The dots are commits and the lines are ... whatever we might mean. Or, maybe it's the wrong answer. I'll take a stab at my own answer here too.